# Loading page com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde amigos,

Eu estava fazendo o seguinte processo para exibir minha página quando feito o carregamento completo da mesma:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.carregado').addClass( 'bye-bye' ).hide('done');
        });
</script>
```

Utilizei o `.addClass` para colocar a classe `.bye-bye` onde ela contém uma animação que faz sumir a `<div>` que ocupa a tela inteira. Até aqui ok!
Como estou usando o seguinte css:

```
.bye-bye{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out; 
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-out; 
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
```

Bom, aqui está o problema, como estou usando o `opacity: 0;` a tela apenas fica transparente, para tentar corrigir adicionei o `.hide(done)`. O `.hide()` funciona, porem ele corta a minha animação na metade.

Bom eu queria de vocês um help, correções, soluções, caso eu não esteja fazendo certo o load, como devo proceder?

Abraço a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outra opção é utilizar o recurso `.load()` do jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

Após a janela carregar, o elemento com a classe `.loader` desaparece.

---

**@atualização:**

Os métodos `.load`, `.unload` e `.error` estão depreciados desde a versão *1.8* do jQuery.

Solução atual `.on('load', function(){...})`:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Colocar um `.hide()` é o mesmo que você fazer `display:none`. E `display` não funciona em animações.

Coloque na sua classe **CSS** uma propriedade:

`visibility:hidden`

Faz a mesma função do `display`, porém, não deleta o elemento do DOM.

E apaga o `.hide()` da função do jQuery.